# Trying to insert products into a category that doesn't exist on compile

Tags: magento2

I've inherited a project that's causing me some headaches.

I'm getting a stream of lines like this one when I run setup:di:compile

```
Error::SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ab83e505_m2`.`catalog_category_product`, CONSTRAINT `CAT_CTGR_PRD_CTGR_ID_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_category_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCA), query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_category_product`(`category_id`, `product_id`) VALUES ('5568','30299');
```

It seems like it's trying to insert products into a category that doesn't exist.

I've searched and category 5568 doesn't exist.

I don't think I can create category 5568, unless anyone knows how to do it via SQL?

I've searched the database over and over again and can't find anywhere to suggest where the products are trying to be inserted into the category.

Anyone come across this before?